# Why is my CSS not applying on my javascript elements?

Tags: javascript, css

Hi in my css file I create following css:

```
 #searchoption.root{
  width:100%;
    top:200px;
    z-index:4;
    background-color:black;
  }

  #searchoption.optionfield{
      background-color: #484848;
      height:150px;
      width:100%;
      z-index:3;
}

 #searchoption.dropbar{
        background-color: #656565;
        height:24px;
        width:100%;
        z-index:4;
        border-color:#828282;
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:0px;
        border-bottom: 1px;
        border-top:1px;
    }
```

and in my js file I create the following:

```
 var searchoptionrootID = "searchoption.root";
var dropbarID = "searchoption.dropbar";
var innershadowID = "searchoption.innershadow";
var optionfieldID = "searchoption.optionfield";
var outershadowID = "searchoption.outershadow";

var searchoptionroot;
var dropbar;
var innershadow;
var outershadow;
var optionfield;

function initSearchOption(){
    // initialisiert die suchoption leiste
    searchoptionroot = document.createElement("div");
    dropbar = document.createElement("div");
    innershadow = document.createElement("div");
    outershadow = document.createElement("div");
    optionfield = document.createElement("div");

    searchoptionroot.setAttribute("id",searchoptionrootID);

    dropbar.setAttribute("id", dropbarID);


    innershadow.setAttribute("id",innershadowID);

    outershadow.setAttribute("id",outershadowID);

    optionfield.setAttribute("id",optionfieldID);


    searchoptionroot.appendChild(optionfield);
    searchoptionroot.appendChild(innershadow);
    searchoptionroot.appendChild(dropbar);
    searchoptionroot.appendChild(outershadow);

    return searchoptionroot;
}
```

In the jsp i just return the object and append it to the document:

but it is not working why?

```
if (searchoption == null ){ 
            searchoption = initSearchOption();

            document.body.appendChild(searchoption);

            alert("height: " + document.getElementById("searchoption.root").style.width);
        }
```

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the `.` character in an ID for CSS.

The CSS selector `#searchoption.root` matches elements with an ID of `searchoption` and a *class* of `root`.

Comment: Yes, you can. ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: Right. Because clearly I couldn't have commented and voted on the answer that was **just plain wrong** before seeing the edit that completely changed it.

Answer (score 0):

`#searchoption.root` means "An element with the id `searchoption` that is a member of the class `root`.

Your element has the id `searchoption.root` and isn't a member of any classes.

Your options:

1. Set the id and class of the element to match the selector
2. Change the selector to `#searchoption\.root`
3. Change the selector and id to use an underscore instead of a period (since underscores don't have special meaning in CSS selectors)

Comment: I changed it to an underscore, but its not displayed anyway. What should I do?

Comment: If you've changed all the selectors and all the ids, then it should work (assuming the style sheet is linked to the document correctly)

Comment: it is, strange... it is only working when I set it up in setAttributes. But I dont want to set it there.  I am running it on a jboss, all in a war file, when I set the elements direclty in the jsp it is working ... but not in the js file

Answer (score 0):

Try without using dot (.) in your element ID.

searchoption.root will be applyed to an element with css class "root" that is a sub element of control with id="searchoption" which does not seem to exist on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Your code work well if you delete points: http://www.jsfiddle.net/pereskokov/uGA72/1/

Also be aware of using consturction `element.style` — in Chrome, for example, this construction returns only styles that were set direct in tag or manualy by javascript, but does not return **computed styles** or **matched css rules**.